# Ошибка: cannot resolve getAssets()

Tags: java, android

Выдаёт ошибку при вызове метода getAssets().
Ошибка cannot resolve 'getAssets()'.
Код:

```
private Drawable getDrawableFromAssets(String path) {
    return Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(path), null);
}

Drawable pickColor() {
    Drawable color[] = new Drawable[]{
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/acqamarin.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/blue.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/green.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/grey.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/night_acqamarin.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/night_blue.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/orange.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/pink.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/red.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/tomato.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/violet.png"),
            getDrawableFromAssets("ball-standart/yellow.png")
    };
    return color[getNumeric(12)];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `getDrawableFromAssets` скорее всего метод класса `Context` а класс, где у вас этот код расположен не является его наследником.

Вам надо или перенести код в актвити или передать в класс/метод ссылку на `Context` и вызывать метод `getDrawableFromAssets` по этой ссылке

Comment: Разобрался, благодарю.

Comment: @J.Defenses, пожалйста) Если ответ помог решить проблему то вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)